# pagination php only 10 items

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a problem with pagination, how to display only 10 items? can do something like this in google - number increased by +5?

[image]

```
<?php
// Make the links to other pages, if necessary.
if ($pages > 1) {

    echo '<br /><p>';
    $current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;

    // If it's not the first page, make a Previous button:
    if ($current_page != 1) {
        echo '<a href="list_photos_4.php?s=' . ($start - $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">Previous</a> ';
    }

    // Make all the numbered pages:
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        if ($i != $current_page) {
            echo '<a href="list_photos_4.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
        } else {
            echo $i . ' ';
        }
    } // End of FOR loop.

    // If it's not the last page, make a Next button:
    if ($current_page != $pages) {
        echo '<a href="list_photos_4.php?s=' . ($start + $display) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">Next</a>';
    }

    echo '</p>'; // Close the paragraph.

} // End of links section.
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change section (Make all the numbered pages) to this:

```
// Make all the numbered pages:
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {    
        if ($i != $current_page) {
            $distance = $current_page - $i;
            if (abs($distance) < 5){
                echo '<a href="list_photos_4.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
            } 
        } else {
            echo $i . ' ';
        }
    } // End of FOR loop
```

I hope this work fine for You.

Comment: hello, thanks for your reply now I have something like this SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for Notice: Undefined variable: i in C:\wamp\www\dwwithphp\public\admin\list_photos_4.php on line 186 - line 186"if ($i != $current_page) {"

Comment: @Mantykora7 just put my solution into for loop: for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {  // MY ANSWER HERE  }

I've just edit my answer. Should work

Comment: yes you are right, something wrong pasted, works well, Thank you for your time and answer:)

Comment: @Mantykora7 I'm glad I could help :) Thanks for approve my answer. PS proszę dodaj jeszcze 1 w górę - odemnie masz + :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Make the links to other pages, if necessary.
if ($pages > 1) {

    // (...)

    $first_disp_page = $cutrrent_page - 5 < 1 ? 1 : $current_page - 5;
    $last_disp_page = $current_page + 5 > $pages ? $pages : $current_page + 5;

    // Make all the numbered pages:
    for ($i = $first_disp_page; $i <= $last_disp_page; $i++) {
        if ($i != $current_page) {
            echo '<a href="list_photos_4.php?s=' . (($display * ($i - 1))) . '&p=' . $pages . '&sort=' . $sort . '">' . $i . '</a> ';
        } else {
            echo $i . ' ';
        }
    } // End of FOR loop.

    // (...)

} // End of links section.
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
// Make all the numbered pages:
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
```

to this:

```
if ($current_page <= 5) $first_page = 1;
else if ($pages - $current_page < 10) $first_page = $pages - 10;
else $first_page = $current_page - 5;

// Make up to 10 numbered pages:
for ($i = $first_page; $i < ($first_page + 10); $i++) {
```

Comment: Hello - works fine when  $display = 2;  - items 25, when $display = 10 items 10 it shows something like this  Previous -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 Next

Comment: I'm not sure what $display is intended to be. That said, `$current_page = ($start/$display) + 1;` seems strange... $current_page should probably just be `(int) $_GET['s']`, although honestly I'm having a hard time understanding your link structure. You should only pass the sort order and the page number, the number of pages should be determined by the server and not sent by the browser. You should clean up your overall code/logic to figure out the fine details.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer - already solved the broblem